# Importing JSON file to Postgres

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, postgresql

Using Node.js I was able to import JSON files to MongoDB, however cannot get an import working when trying with Postgres.

Below is my Node.js file:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var pg = require('pg');

var json = fs.readFileSync('testfile.json').toString();

pg.connect('postgres://test:test@localhost/tl', function(err, 
client, done) {
if (err) {
    console.log('error: ', err);
    process.exit(1);
}
client.query(json, function(err, result) {
    done();
    if (err) {
        console.log('error: ', err);
        process.exit(1);
    }
    process.exit(0);
 });
});
```

Here is my JSON file:

```
[{
"id": 43947231,
"dateModified": null,
"jobTaskId": {
    "id": 16089453
},
"billable": true,
}]
```

It seems to connect fine, but it doesn't seem to like my JSON formatting. I have tried various formats, however the same error. Here is the error I get from Postgres:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "[" at character 1
STATEMENT:
```

Answer (score 0):

Postgresql doesn't use JSON for queries like MongoDB does, it uses a query language. You can't just plug in MongoDB commands and get the same results. If you want to use Postgresql, you'll have to learn SQL.

See the [pg documentation on npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg).